# When installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, what (if anything) is installed at the location specified using the "Device for boot loader installation" option?

Tags: grub2, uefi, ubiquity

When installing Ubuntu using the “Something else” option, a "Device for boot loader installation" option is presented.

I understand that, when installing Ubuntu in BIOS mode, the "Device for boot loader installation" option controls where (within which boot sector) portions of GRUB will be installed.

But, if I understand correctly, when installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, much of GRUB is installed within the EFI System Partition (ESP), with the remainder being installed within the Ubuntu file system.  That is, *no portion of GRUB* is installed into a boot sector when installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode.  (Please let me know if I am wrong regarding where GRUB is installed when  installing Ubuntu in UEFI  mode.)

**QUESTION**:  When installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, what (if anything) is installed at the location specified using the "Device for boot loader installation" option?

Comment: Nothing. It just defaults to the first drive's ESP, usually sda's ESP. But it seems to also find NVMe drive with an ESP. Same selection with Fedora let me install to an ESP on my sdb drive, but Ubuntu does not. I had hoped they updated 18.04, but it still overwrote my main working install, still 16.04's entry in /EFI/ubuntu in ESP on sda.

Comment: @oldfred  Thanks!  I've suspected that the "Device for boot loader installation" option is an artifact from the BIOS mode installation, and doesn't apply to UEFI mode installation.  Good to get some confirmation.

Comment: @oldfred  As for the default ESP install location issue, there's a workaround:  1) use gparted to change the "flag" on the original ESP  from "esp" to "msftdata";  2) while leaving the original ESP in place, create a new ESP (FAT32) using gparted, and then set the flag for it to "esp" using the Manage Flags tool in gparted;  3) during installation using the "something else" option, the Ubuntu installer should (by default) use the newly created ESP during installation; and then 4) revert the flag on the original ESP from "msftdata" to  "esp".

Comment: I have not gotten it to change drives. It wants to default to first drive's ESP. And it seems to error if no ESP on sda.

Comment: @oldfred It defaults to the first drive's ESP even if you change its flag to "msftdata"? Hmm, that's not what happens on any of my systems. Maybe your UEFI is unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a Canonical employee who has knowledge of the subject, and that employee replied as follows:

> "You're right; [the 'Device for boot loader installation' option is]
>   ignored for EFI-mode installations."